# acegi security - targetURL keeping "#xxx"

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

Just a quick question that I am having trouble phrasing well enough to google sucessfully.

Is is possible in acegi security + Spring to keep the "full" targetURL post login?

i.e. if a user tries to go to "http://www.mysite.com/mypage.html**#search~789**" to have acegi/spring navigate them back to that point post login instead of ""http://www.mysite.com/mypage.html"

Cheers,
Rob

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `#xxx` [fragment identifier](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fragment_identifier) is not sent to the server by the browser (you would have to check if that's the practice only or required by some RFC/standard). So for your case you can't read the `#xxx` part in Acegi/Spring Security.

It's not clear why you would want to do this, but you could always try to read the value in JavaScript (client-side) and have it sent to the server in other way.

Comment: Thank you Grzegorz, I didnt realise that fragment was not sent to the server.  I will look for other ways around the problem.  The reason I was looking to do it was to go directly to certain states within a GWT application I have been writing.
R